# Hybris Product Cockpit Attributes Section

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using Hybris 6.2 and while creating a product in electronics staged site in Product Cockpit, the Attributes section (below Basics) is not opening and when i tried to open it for an existing product its not opening for them as well. Would anyone know why?

Comment: I think we need some more information. Do you speak from the old productcockpit (/productcockpit) or the new productcockpit (in the /backoffice). Then, what does the LOG say? Are there any information? Did you some changes?

Comment: https://imgur.com/xeeeUhY

Comment: I've updated the old productcockpit, i have added a new category(Rugged) and also mapped it to some OOTB categories like Canon and Digital Cameras. See the picture here https://imgur.com/xeeeUhY

Comment: Its in the old version (productcockpit), I've added a new product Powershot D10 and made a new category(Rugged) and also mapped it to some OOTB categories like Canon and Digital Cameras. See the picture here imgur.com/xeeeUhY

Answer (score 1):

Did you assign a classification category (with classification attributes) or a category mapped to a classification category to the product? If not, then that could be a possible reason why the product doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: I've added a new product Powershot D10 and made a new category(Rugged) and also mapped it to some OOTB categories like Canon and Digital Cameras. See the picture here imgur.com/xeeeUhY

Comment: @sagar What is is the exact version you are using? 6.2.0.x? There's a defect with the Attributes section below a certain version. So if you are using a version older than 6.2.0.4, then it may be caused by that issue (ECP-465): https://jira.hybris.com/browse/PATCH-2949